# Use PHP to round floats that aren't like 1.05

Tags: php

Is it possible to round a number where if it's .5, just leave it, anything below .5 round down, anything above .5 round up?

For example:

- `5.0 * 1.35 = 6.75 // leave it`
- `5.2 * 1.35 = 7.02 // round down to 7.00`
- `5.5 * 1.35 = 7.56 // round up to 8.00`

I've formatted with `round($n,0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP)` where $n is the product from the above calc , which leaves 6.75 but returns 7.02 for the next one. I also tried `round($n,-1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP)` which gives me the 7.00 on the second calc but then of course won't return a 6.75  for the first, instead it returns 680.

This is a ticket markup calculation where the user enters the first number and is multiplied by the second. I actually remove the decimal because they don't want to see it, and they want this sort of customized rounding on the result.

Comment: If what's 5.. the hundredth digit?

Comment: This seems like a rather arbitrary thing to do. Are you sure you wouldn't want to round to the nearest 5 instead? e.g. `round(2*$num)/2`

Comment: You ask about not round the first decimal (.5) then you go and present an example of not rounding the 2nd decimal. Make up your mind, one of both, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function myround($num, $prec) {
  $rhu = round($num, $prec, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
  $rhd = round($num, $prec, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);

  return ($rhu + $rhd) / 2;
}
```

Works for any precision you like. For hundreth's place, as in the example, `$prec` would need to be 2.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to determine the value of the last non-zero digit of a given floating point number in PHP is to convert it to a string.

```
$str = (string) $float;
$result = ($str[strlen($str) - 1] == 5) ? $float : round($float);
```

[Example](http://codepad.org/rjihTjgD)

Of course, no matter what you do it will be subject to a small margin of error because of the [floating point precision](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
$n = round($n, 2);
if($n % .05 != 0 || $n % .1 == 0)
{
  $n = round($n);
}
```

Does this work for you? I'm assuming the `5` you speak of is the hundredth digit, and if it's not `5` then you want a whole number.

Comment: He wants 5 in the tenths place. `it's .5, just leave it, anything...`

Comment: That's strange. Why he giving examples like `1.05` and `1.35`? >_<

Comment: I think `1.05` is a typo in the title... and `1.35` is some constant he is using, or an example?

Comment: He says `6.75 // leave it` so I think I'm good lol..as long as the algorithm works. I haven't tested it

Comment: Heh, you are correct. Typos galore. Kind of like office space, if you have seen it, a comma or a decimal mistaske never hurts anybody. lol

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12315/discussion-between-ryan-b-and-shredder)